# Написать функцию, которая вычисляет длину самого длинного строго возрастающего подотрезка

Tags: c++

Есть некоторая последовательность s1,s2...sn, подотрезком которой называется непрерывная подпоследовательность вида si,s(i+1)...s(j-1), i <= j. Необходимо написать функцию, которая принимает последовательность, хранящуюся в std::list, по двум итераторам, и вычисляет для неё длину самого длинного строго возрастающего подотрезка. Копировать элементы запрещено, тип элементов в list неизвестен.
Данная реализация не проходит тест при длине list = 2

```
template<class It>
size_t max_increasing_len(It p, It q)
{
    size_t size = 0;
    int index = 0;

    if (p == q) return 0;
    else if (p == --q) return 1;
    else ++q;

    for (; p != q;)
    {
        if (*p < *++p)
        {
            index++;
        }
        else if (index > size)
        {
            size = ++index;
            index = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            index = 0;
        }
    }

    return index > size ? index : size;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if (*p < *++p)` - [неопределённое поведение](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5). Если в выражении используется результат `++p`, запрещено там же использовать значение `p`.

Это по стандарту. А на деле компилятор может преобразовать ваш код в следующее:

```
++p;
if (*p < *p)
```

А потом сообразить что в условии тождественная ложь и выбросить условный оператор из кода программы вообще.

Вы думаете я шучу? Нет, порядок вычисления аргументов оператора `<` не определяется стандартом.

[Order of evaluation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order):

> Order of evaluation of any part of any expression, including order of evaluation of function arguments is *unspecified* (with some exceptions listed below). The compiler can evaluate operands and other subexpressions in any order, and may choose another order when the same expression is evaluated again.
>
> There is no concept of left-to-right or right-to-left evaluation in C++. This is not to be confused with left-to-right and right-to-left associativity of operators: the expression `a() + b() + c()` is parsed as `(a() + b()) + c()` due to left-to-right associativity of operator+, but `c()` may be evaluated first, last, or between `a()` or `b()` at run time...

В вашем случае компилятор может скомпилировать код к, примеру, двумя способами:

```
auto a = *p;
auto b = *++p;
if (a < b)      // тут всё работает как ожидается
```

```
auto b = *++p;
auto a = *p;
if (a < b)      // тут ничего не работает
```

Пока вы учитесь, избегайте инкрементов в составе выражений. `++p;` - можно, `*++p` или что-то сложнее - нельзя.

**P.S.** Что-такое будет работать:

```
template<class It>
size_t max_increasing_len(It p, It q) {
    if (p == q) {
        return 0;
    }

    size_t max_so_far = 1;
    size_t max_ending_here = 1;
    for (It pp = p++; p != q; pp = p++) {
        if (*pp < *p) {
            ++max_ending_here;
        } else {
            max_so_far = std::max(max_so_far, max_ending_here);
            max_ending_here = 1;
        }
    }
    return std::max(max_so_far, max_ending_here);
}
```

Comment: При использовании такой конструкции я получаю error: use of deleted function ‘String::String(const String&)’ auto a = *p; и аналогично для b:
`for (; p != q;){auto a = *p; auto b = *++p;
        if (a < b)...`
Попытался создать временную переменную prev_p, в которую записываю p и далее декрементирую prev_p,  но получаю ошибку времени выполнения.

Answer (score 0):

`

```
template<class It>
size_t max_increasing_len(It p, It q){
    int cnt = 0, max = 0;
    for(It iter = p, temp; iter != q; ++iter) {
        if (cnt != 0 && *(--(temp = iter)) < *iter) {
            ++cnt;
        } else {
            max = cnt > max ? cnt : max;
            cnt = 1;
        }
    }
    return max = cnt > max ? cnt : max
```

`

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: `--(temp = iter)` -> `iter - 1`.

Comment: `int` -> `size_t`.